# Installing Linux 4.3 on existing Ubuntu release

Tags: package-management, kernel

Suppose we have a stable Ubuntu release installed, such as 15.04 or 14.10 (my case). Suppose we have no interest in upgrading userland software, but have a dire need for a state-of-the-art kernel (in my case: to try the recent `nouveau` driver).

- Is (trying to) run a stable Ubuntu on this unstable kernel practical? (as of September 15, 2015)
- If it is, then is (trying to) install an unstable kernel *as a package* practical?
- If it is, then **how to ?**

#### What was tried:

Looking at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-rc1-unstable/ and observing “build logs” with `make` errors, a multimegabyte “patch”, and `linux-headers-4.3.0-040300rc1_4.3.0-040300rc1.201509122030_all.deb` (understandably) without a single kernel C source file inside.

Comment: The kernel PPA you've tried is a good choice, I'd expect the debs for 4.3 to become a lot more usable very soon. Weather or not it's practical, depends on your expectations and requirements. For example, I wouldn't expect too much stabilty out of it.

Comment: You do not need C source file to install a kernel. Just install the debs.

Comment: @Pilot6: Do you know where *binaries* lie? Then give a link, please, instead of telling obvious truths.

Comment: The deb files ARE the binaries to install.

Comment: @Pilot6: OK, second try. Do you know where *debs containing Linux 4.3 binaries* lie?

Comment: I see your point. The have not been uploaded there yet. You can build them yourself from kernel.org, or wait till they are uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu kernel technicians made their job, meanwhile.

Dowloading [this](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-rc1-unstable/linux-image-4.3.0-040300rc1-generic_4.3.0-040300rc1.201509160642_amd64.deb) and [this](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-rc1-unstable/linux-headers-4.3.0-040300rc1-generic_4.3.0-040300rc1.201509160642_amd64.deb) and

```
sudo dpkg --install
```

on both packages solved the problem.

#### Result:

Linux duk 4.3.0-040300rc1-generic #201509160642 SMP Wed Sep 16 10:44:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
and Xorg without [that annoying snow](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:GeForce_8600_GTS_malfunction.ogg)!